# Codeigniter vote routine review

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model that I've created in Codeigniter to represent a vote. The purpose of the site that it's a part of is to allow users to vote on their preferred pronunciation for a given word.

The routine first checks to see if a user has registered a vote for the given pronunciation and if so, whether it was up or down. Just like the stackexchange network sites, you can only vote either up or down for a given entry and you can only vote once in either direction. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here (such as adding a method or two)? If there's anything else that you'd like to see that I haven't posted, let me know.

```
public function vote($pronun_id, $user_id, $direction) {
        $data = array(
                'pronun_id' => $pronun_id,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'direction' => $direction
            );
        $already_voted = $this->_vote_exists($pronun_id, $user_id);

        if($already_voted == 'up') {
            if($direction == 'up') {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'pronun_id' => $pronun_id));
                $this->db->update('vote', array('direction' => $direction));
                return true;
            }
        }
        elseif($already_voted == 'down') {
            if($direction == 'down') {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'pronun_id' => $pronun_id));
                $this->db->update('vote', array('direction' => $direction));
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->db->insert('vote', $data);
            return true;
        }       
    }

    private function _vote_exists($pronun_id, $user_id) {
        $data = $data = array(
                'pronun_id' => $pronun_id,
                'user_id' => $user_id
            );
        $query = $this->db->get_where('vote', $data);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row_array();
            return $row['direction'];
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Also, I'm very new to Codeigniter, so please feel free to be brutal about anything here. I'm not the best programmer and I also just don't know Codeigniter "style" yet, so either of those may be issues here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some cut and pasted code which can be re-factored by comparing already_voted with the direction rather than with 'up' and 'down' specifically.

```
if ($already_voted === false) {
    $this->db->insert('vote', $data);
    return true;
}
elseif ($already_voted == $direction) {
    return false;
}
else {
    $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'pronun_id' => $pronun_id));
    $this->db->update('vote', array('direction' => $direction));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that was kind of clunky but I can't believe I didn't think of this solution.